# Heads Up Notification getting dismissed after few second

Tags: android, android-notifications, heads-up-notifications

I am trying to make a heads up notification through the code below and want it to to be persistent until the user decide to dismiss it. But it is getting dismissed automatically after few second (around 10 sec). Is there any way to make it persistent and leave it to the user to dismiss it.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setContentTitle("Notification")
.setContentText("Hello !!!")
.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
"View Call", null)
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher,
"Call Back", null);

// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManager notificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
```

Comment: "But it is getting dismissed automatically after few second (around 10 sec)" -- if by "dismissed", you mean that it turns into a normal `Notification` with an icon in the status bar, that is expected behavior.

Comment: Yes, it turns into a normal notification

Comment: Try to use setAutoCancel(false)

Comment: setAutoCancel(false) is not working as per my requirement .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code snippet worked for me.

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        PendingIntent piDismiss = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        //build notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
        .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
        .setContentTitle("Ping Notification")
        .setContentText("You have a new notification.")
        .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL) // must requires VIBRATE permission
        .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT) //must give priority to High, Max which will considered as heads-up notification
        .addAction(R.drawable.dismiss,
        "View Call", piDismiss)
        .addAction(R.drawable.ic_ok,
        "ok", null)
        .setFullScreenIntent(piDismiss, true);
```